# Xamarin Forms Android slows down with increasing navigation depth

Tags: android, performance, listview, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app I have a ListView with 15000 items. I use a background task (Task.Factory.StartNew()) to calculate data for batches of 300 items and update a list item property used in a Binding, signaling the PropertyChanged event on the UI thread (Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread).

When the ListView is presented in a root page of the app, the UI is snappy and fast.

When the ListView is presented 2 pages deep (root->page->list page), the UI is a little sluggish to open and scroll etc.

When the ListView is presented 3 pages deep (root->page->page->list page) the UI is slow in general and locks up while doing the background calculations.

Android shows this behavior the most, especially with slightly outdated hardware. But the UI thread should not be starved more on older devices?

The intermediate pages are of varying complexity, but nothing crazy, and uses no background tasks.

The app in general takes care to use almost all of the regular recommended optimization techniques for Xamarin, but frankly the returns are minimal.

Has anyone else seen the correlation between navigation depth and performance on Xamarin Forms for Android? Any pitfalls, fixes, tricks?

Edit:
To be more specific anyway - I navigate with Navigation.PushAsync() and Navigation.PushModalAsync(), testing on a mix of 2016 Samsung tablets and emulators of various Android versions. A modern device is able to keep up, but slowdown is still noticable.

Edit:
So, as comments correctly alludes, navigation depth itself shouldn't be a problem. Looking more thoroughly at the content that fills the intermediate pages, I am finding misbehaving ListViews (not my monster 15000-item list) that eats cpu. This one doesn't use common optimisation tricks, but is also not doing anything out of the ordinary. When passing such a page, going deeper into the app, the cpu load accumulates.

This is an example that (for me) spawns an infinite loop of binding properties over and over again (in this example IsDiscountVisible and Discount). In this list there are 10 items. CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" here triggers the behavior.

I will try to clean up the corresponding C# code and post it when done. Perhaps something obvious is found there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GeneroSales.UI.Views.ProductTemplatePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="Products" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" HasUnevenRows="False"
                  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label
                                IsVisible="{Binding IsDiscountVisible}"
                                Text="{Binding Discount}"></Label>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: "I have a ListView with 15000 items" - how much of this data is a user on a mobile device actually going to access?

Comment: 15000 is an extreme edge case, but the use exists. The performance behavior is visible and unsatisfactory with as low as 300 items. Note the app handles 15000 items without breaking a sweat if it is the root page. I am curious to see if anything in the framework consumes UI thread the deeper you go.

Comment: I find it unlikely that performance would depend on the navigation path unless you are doing something very unusual.  Without any code or a [mcve] it’s difficult to say more

Comment: I understand that you have a test case that seems to demonstrate that, but I'm going to go out on a limb here: Whatever is actually happening is not what you think is happening. Such behavior isn't how any platform works, whether use Xamarin.Forms or not. Impossible to say more, unless you make a github public repo with an example that demonstrates, as Jason mentioned. However, I'm assuming you are using the word **navigation** correctly (changing whole screen to another page), and don't instead mean that the pages are **nested** (visible at same time, one page inside another).

Comment: How did you navigate between these pages? In addition, which kind of device did you test on? The emulator or the physical device?

Comment: Right. I was seeing things where there were none, and all your comments have helped me see that, making me look harder elsewhere. It was not navigating deeper in itself that slowed things down, but the content in the pages I passed while going deeper.
Instead innocent (to me) looking ListViews behaves badly, and I updated my question with a part of such an example. I will dig more into that example and update with my findings. Thanks everyone that spent time, I never meant for my first ever Stack Overflow post to be a _rubber duck_ question.

Comment: You can try to use the collectionview instead of the listview.